# Nested functions inside a class in tkinter python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

> When I click on the button (Report_But) the report function runs but when I select a date object from the tkcalendar, the my_upd function remains silent (does not run). When I remove the class and adjust the alignment, the code runs perfectly

*Please how can nested functions run inside a class*

**Here is the code**

```
from tkinter import *
class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mainw = Tk()
        self.mainw.title("Daily sales report")
        width = 1000
        height = 700
        screen_width = self.mainw.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = self.mainw.winfo_screenheight()
        x = (screen_width / 2) - (width / 2)
        y = (screen_height / 2) - (height / 2)
        self.mainw.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (width, height, x, y))
        self.mainw.resizable(0, 0)
        self.frame = Frame(self.mainw, width=1000, height=700, bg="#FFFFFF")
        self.frame.place(x=0, y=0)
        self.frameinfo = self.frame.place_info()
        self.reportbut = Button(self.frame, text="Report_But", font="roboto 14", bd=5, width=8, bg="#FFFFFF",
                                command=self.report)
        self.reportbut.place(x=10, y=5, height=40, width = 200)
    def report(self):
        import tkinter as tk
        from tkinter import ttk
        from tkcalendar import DateEntry
        import sqlite3
        self.my_win = tk.Tk()
        self.my_win.geometry("1350x800")  # Size of the window
        self.my_win.title("Christ the light limitd")  # Adding a title
        self.sel = tk.StringVar()
        self.cal = DateEntry(self.my_win, selectmode='day', textvariable=self.sel)
        self.cal.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=30)
        def my_upd(*args):
            if (len(self.sel.get()) > 4):
                date = self.cal.get_date()  # get selected date object from calendar
                date1 = date.strftime('%y-%m-%d')  # format for MySQL date column
                date2 = date.strftime("%d-%B-%Y")  # format to display at label
                self.le1.config(text=date2)  # display date at Label
                conn = sqlite3.connect(r'E:\report.db')
                c = conn.cursor()
                query = ("select * from sales where Date = :d")
                c.execute(query, (date1,))
                saleslist = c.fetchall()
                for item in self.trv.get_children():  # delete all previous listings
                    self.trv.delete(item)
                total = 0  # to store total sale of the selected date
                for data in saleslist:
                    self.trv.insert("", 'end', iid=data[0], text=data[0],
                                    values=(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4], data[5], data[6]))
                    total = round(total + (data[5]), 2)
                self.le2.config(text="Total: " + str(total) + "ssp")  # show total value
        self.le1 = tk.Label(self.my_win, font=('Times', 22, 'bold'), fg='blue')
        self.le1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.trv = ttk.Treeview(self.my_win, selectmode='browse')
        self.trv.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=20, pady=20)
        # number of columns
        self.trv["columns"] = ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7")
        self.trv['height'] = 20
        # Defining heading
        self.trv['show'] = 'headings'
        # width of columns and alignment
        self.trv.column("1", width=100, anchor='c')
        self.trv.column("2", width=100, anchor='c')
        self.trv.column("3", width=100, anchor='c')
        self.trv.column("4", width=100, anchor='c')
        self.trv.column("5", width=100, anchor='c')
        self.trv.column("6", width=100, anchor='c')
        self.trv.column("7", width=100, anchor='c')
        # respective columns
        self.trv.heading("1", text="Transaction ID")
        self.trv.heading("2", text="Invoice No.")
        self.trv.heading("3", text="Product ID")
        self.trv.heading("4", text="Description")
        self.trv.heading("5", text="Quantity")
        self.trv.heading("6", text="Total Price")
        self.trv.heading("7", text="Date")
        self.sel.trace('w', my_upd)
        self.le2 = tk.Label(self.my_win, font=('Times', 22, 'bold'), fg='red')
        self.le2.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='ne', pady=20)
        self.my_win.mainloop()
w=Main()
w.mainw.mainloop()
```

> sorry I could not post the error message here but when you run this code, you will understand my query.

Comment: Why can't you post the error message?

Comment: It is because you have created more than one instance of `Tk()`.  Use `Toplevel()` inside function `report()`.

Comment: Thanks. My question has got the right answer. I used TopLevel() inside my report() and it worked pretty well.